# Firebase - How many databases can be created?

Tags: firebase

Is there a limit to the number of databases that could be created in Firebase. Each database would have it's own login and security credentials to keep the data separate.

```
https://xyz_customer_one.firebaseio.com
https://xyz_customer_two.firebaseio.com
https://xyz_customer_three.firebaseio.com
     . . .
https://xyz_customer_ONE_MILLION.firebaseio.com
```

Comment: Could somebody please explain the reason for the down vote?  I would like to know what I did wrong when composing the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have up to 10 Firebase projects on the free plan. There is no limit on the number of paid Firebases.

Comment: *[Disclosure: I work for Firebase]* We do root for you reaching that number of course. :-)