# Create an app automatically on firebase

Tags: firebase

I have a very specific task to carry out. I need to create an app within firebase, but doing so without manually creating an application, i.e click and enter. So far I have not found an api for going about creating an app "programmatically" (restAPI, android, or anything else).

Creating a script would force me to check out authentication protocols and mimic them. However, should they change the protocols for some reason, my script would fail.

So, my question is; how can I go about creating an app within Firebase without creating a script?

Comment: Firebase does not have an API for automatically creating new apps. In most valid use-cases, you can host multiple of your customers in a single Firebase database. `/customer1/theirdata` and `/customer2/theirdata`. Otherwise you'll indeed have to create them manually. Keep in mind that you're limited to 10 free apps per Firebase account.

Comment: This poses another question, is there a limit to non-free apps?

Comment: Nope. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550873/firebase-how-many-databases-can-be-created

Comment: Great.  Thanks for the quick reply! I know I can use 1 app with multiple data points using custom urls. My customers are just really picky abour their data. Creating separate apps enables me to charge them differently. Well, makes it easier anyway.