# How to create a new firebase app programmatically?

Tags: firebase

When I signed up for a firebase account, 'my first app' was already created for me.  Having my google credentials, how do I programmatically crate a new app and perhaps even upgrade it to a desired plan?  This is all about infrastructure as code and I'd hate to write phantom scripts for this.

Comment: The quick start guides on the Firebase website are spot on and explain in detail how to craft the beginnings of the app from the ground up; adding headers etc and then short piece of sample code to write to your database.

Comment: There's an npm module for this https://github.com/casetext/firebase-admin

Comment: Since there are three responses and an answer that are not the same. We probably need more information as to what you are specifically asking.

Answer (score 3):

Firebase doesn't have a public API to create new apps or upgrade existing ones.

See:

- [Create a new firebase app from API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763839/create-a-new-firebase-app-from-api)
- [Create an app automatically on firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30804926/create-an-app-automatically-on-firebase)